# Counting .tif value in polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, zonal-statistics

I am trying to count raster values (from a .tif file) in polygons. In previous posts that people suggested using the 'zonal statistics' plugin in QGIS. However, I couldn't find it in my plugin manager (QGIS 3.6). I have ticked the box to show experimental plugins, but still couldn't find it. Any idea what is causing this?

If the plugin doesn't work, what would be a good alternative to use?

Comment: I believe zonal statistics is not a plugin, but rather integrated into the raster tools of QGIS. Just search for "zonal statistics" in the toolbox panel (I don't see it listed in the dropdown menu of QGIS 3.4).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Zonal Statistics` used to be a plugin, but it's now located in the Processing Toolbox (screenshot from QGIS 3.6).

[image]

Many tools which were originally created as external plugins, were later incorporated into the core QGIS program. In general if you're following a tutorial created in an earlier version of QGIS and you can't find a tool mentioned in the tutorial, check the Processing Toolbox.

Note that the Processing Toolbox itself is a core plugin. This means it comes pre-installed, but you might need to *enable* it. Open the Plugin manager (Plugin menu > Manage and install plugins...). Search for "Processing", and click the checkbox next to the plugin name.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I found it! Really appreciate all your help!